# ListView drawableLeft of header view changes position

Tags: android, listview, styles

I'm attaching a layout ass headerView to my list view. However when I do it loses it's style (namely the drawableLeft changes positions).

This is the header view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    style="@style/header"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_setup"
    android:text="@string/fragment_contacts"
    android:contentDescription="@string/fragment_contacts"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="readMe"
    android:textColor="?attr/color1" />
```

[image]

This is how I add it to the listview

```
        ((TextView) header).setText(getString(R.string.fragment_favorites));
        listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

And this is the final result when the listView is rendered and the drawableLeft changes position:

[image]

How do I keep the DrawableLeft in it's correct position next to the text?

Comment: Why aren't use a horizontal `LinearLayout` with `ImageView` and `TextView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/YOUR_TEXTVIEW"
        ....
        />

</FrameLayout>
```